# No output using a node delta calculator

Tags: node.js

I found this package and I tried to use it because I would like to see differences in JSON: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-multilevel-delta

This is what I tried:

```
// row.old = "{\"current_page\":1,\"data\":[{\"id\":6430,\"name\":\"A random name\",\"code\":\"rname13\",\"description\":\"rname13test ...
// row.new = "{\"current_page\":1,\"data\":[{\"id\":6430,\"name\":\"A random name 2\",\"code\":\"rname13\",\"description\":\"rname13test ...
const oldData = JSON.parse(row.old);
const newData = JSON.parse(row.new);
const difference = jsonMultilevelDelta.json(oldData, newData);
console.log(difference);
```

However for some reason I am not getting any result, am I using it wrong?

Comment: Can you post the old and new json?

Comment: I have posted a part of the old and new data, `row.old` and `row.new` are both JSON.stringify data

Comment: May be row.old is equal to row.new. That is why it is printing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it, it is only finding the difference by looking for missing properties, not by looking at the difference in values. I don't know if it was designed to meet your requirements.

It also has low weekly downloads and little activity so probably not the best thing you want in a project, imo.

Comment: Alright thank you, bit off-topic but do you know any libraries to check for json differences from the top of your head?

Comment: Would you want to compare two objects / JSON and return each key/value pair that is different or missing? Or would true for equal and false for different suffice?

Comment: I would like to return new json that contains the changed key/values

Comment: If that is the case then unfortunately I don't. Would be a good exercise for you to DIY, else if I get time over the next few weeks I might take it on as a challenge. Good luck!